# aiobotocore==2.3.4 requires botocore<1.24.22,>=1.24.21 but botocore 1.27.55 was resolved

Tags: python, pip, boto3, requirements.txt, pex

I am getting the below error while I'm trying to build pex file on a remote server and I'm putting **boto3** in my **requirements.txt** and not botocore or aioboto in my file but still getting this

**aiobotocore==2.3.4 requires botocore<1.24.22,>=1.24.21 but botocore 1.27.55 was resolved**

I would really apreciate some help on this.

Comment: From some other requirement/dependencies of your requirements `pip` has determined that it needs `botocore 1.27.55`, but `aiobotocore==2.3.4` has conflicting requirements. From the information that you have provided, no real solution can be offered. You will need to go back to your requirements.txt and relax version constraints

Comment: Hey, really thanks for this but I didn't put any version constraint on boto3. It's just boto3 in my requirements file without any mentioned version. Neither aioboto nor botocore

Comment: You presumably have two different things that depend on botocore. boto3 will depend on it and then you likely have something else that depends on aiobotcore which then depends on botocore.